# Application defined or Object defined error. Copy from worksheet to sheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a piece of code that checks if a file is open or not and based on that criteria copies and pastes cell information. When the program runs I get an error message that says "Application defined or Object defined error". The line where the error is thrown is commented.

```
' check if the file is open

Ret = Isworkbookopen("\\showdog\service\Service Jobs.xlsm")
If Ret = False Then
' open file
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("\\showdog\service\Service Jobs.xlsm")
Set destSheet = wkbDest.Sheets("Customer Information")
'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Report")

shttocopy.Range("A11:J11").Resize(xlDown).Copy       'error is on this line 

destSheet.Range("A4:J4").Cells(xlDown).PasteSpecial


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wkbDest.Save
wkbDest.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that range (A11 to J11)? Copy a range from row 11 to the next row with info in it (using resize)?

Comment: It was suggested to me by someone else as I started running out of ideas on how to solve this problem. The concept of this is to take that range and run through the columns and copy all the info in each of the rows (total number is unknown) and paste it into another sheet. Now that I think about it I am not sure if i made that clear in my description.

Comment: I tried "value" as well in place of resize. I am able to get it to paste the last cell with the "end" method, but I can't figure out how to get the entire thing to paste.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code to get you started:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Integer, lastCol As Integer, startRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

startRow = 11 'starting in row 11 - you can change this.

'Create and name the new worksheet, which you will paste into.
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'add to end of workbook
ActiveSheet.Name = "New Sheet"
Set newWS = Sheets("New Sheet")

' Starting in cell A11, what's the last row in that group of cells?
With ws
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(startRow + 1, 1)) Then ' this will check to see if there's only one row of data.
            lastRow = startRow ' If A12 is blank, you don't want last row to be 66000, so just set 11 as the last row
        Else
            lastRow = .Cells(startRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    End If
    ' Starting in cell A11, how many columns to the right are there?
    lastCol = .Cells(startRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    ' Now, let's copy your range - NOTE: You don't need copy, so I commented this out.  But this would copy it if you didn't.
    ' .Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
End With

' Paste the data into the new sheet
Dim newLastRow As Integer 'what row is the starting row for your info?
newLastRow = newWS.Cells(66000, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'starting in A66000, what's the next row with info? Add one because you want to start on the next blank row

newWS.Range(newWS.Cells(startRow, 1), newWS.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)) = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

You don't necessarily need Copy/Paste - you can set one range's value equal to that of another.

Without any idea as to why you want to paste into Row 4 on your new sheet, I just have this copying your data to the same range as your original sheet.  If you let me know why row 4 (is that the "next" open row, starting at row 1?), I can make some tweaks.

I hope the code makes sense, I tried to comment so it would.  Naturally, you would need to feather this in to your variables, but it should get you going.

As for resize(), I'm pretty sure you have to declare both column and row resizing.  If you're not resizing the width (columns) or height (rows), just put "1" as the resize number.